# Why cant I use ONNX Runtime training with pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, onnxruntime

When I run

`from onnxruntime.capi.ort_trainer import ORTTrainer`

as stated at https://github.com/microsoft/onnxruntime/#training-start, I get this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'onnxruntime.capi.ort_trainer'`

What can I do to fix this?
I have onnxruntime installed via pip but I couldn't even find "ort_trainer.py" in [python path]/site_packages/onnx-runtime/capi

Answer (score 1):

You should build ort training from source.
https://www.onnxruntime.ai/docs/how-to/build.html#training